# Making a variable unchangeable once stored

Tags: java

**EDIT**-
Sorry I may have been unclear in what im asking, the code works in finding the maximum. But once its stored how would I set the variable so If I wanted to change it in the future I can't

Comment: What is patient info? Are patients store in the memory when the program is closed? If patients info is just collection of integers just find the maximum.
WHAT DOES NOT WORK? WHAT IS THE ERROR?

Comment: Patient Info is a linked list where things such as name, address etc is stored. But once once the maximum is found and stored, I then want it so it cannot be modified in the future.

Comment: @Moley see my answer

Comment: @Yoda They aren't stored just what is inputted in that session. The problem is I can edit the ID to be anything once stored in the linkedList, I want the ID once saved to be unchangeable

Comment: You haven't posted enough context... is `IDCount` a Class variable, an instance variable, or a local variable within a method?  Is the `for (int i=0...` loop part of the same constructor or method as all the `PatientInfo.add()` calls, or separate? Is the overall code posted (aside from IDCount) part of a constructor or a method? I can't tell at all what `this.patientID` refers to. Is `PatientInfo` an object or a Class with static methods?

Comment: @Moley you can't do that. As programmer you will always be able to compromise your code. Maybe what you really want is to implement **unique constraint** on the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

As you initialise the value to zero you check if it is zero and if so it can be updated.

```
if (patientId == 0) patientId = IDCount +1;
```

Of course to make this more robust, the patientId  should be a private field in another class and the setting should be done in a `setter` with the above logic.

On a further note, if you are simply want to get use the maximum value, consider using [Math.max](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int))

Comment: I don't see how that would stop me in the future accessing the array and being able to change the ID

Comment: because once it is set it will no longer be zero

Answer (score 1):

First: Declare your final variable without an initial value. 
Second: Use a *temporary variable* to compute the unique value. 
Last: Load the temporary value into your final variable.

If it is an instance variable, you'll have to do this computation *into every constructor*.

**Update**

```
class MyClass
{
    private final int patientID;

    public MyClass()
    {
        int temp = IDCount;
        for (int i=0; PatientInfo.contains(temp) && i < 9999999;i++){
            temp++;
        }
        this.patientID=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i try to do that I get an error "The local variable PatientID may not have been initialized"

Comment: Yes: That means that you have to prevent the case in which the loop does not iterate not a single time.

Comment: Sorry Im pretty new to java, explain a little?

Comment: Im still getting an error now "The final field AppointmentManager.patientID cannot be assigned"

Comment: Relax, my friend: There's nothing wrong in that code, but it is obviously incomplete. You should add an **edit** to your post and include the _full class source code_, and also explain what and where (line) is the error now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create somewhere (probably in the `PatientInfo` class) a **static** field representing the current maximum `PatientID`.

Then just assign that number+1 to the newly created `Patient` and change the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to seems to be pointless. I think you might just want to implement **unique constraint** on the specified attribute. But if you really want an "once mutable int", you got it:

```
class CustomInt {
   private Integer val;

   public void setVal(int val) throws Exception{
       if(val != null)
          throw new Exception("cannot reassign");
       this.val = val;
   }
}
```

But as I marked, it is pointless.